# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0xff651fd8 in tid 31228 Setting up binding context

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to deploy my first Xamarin app on my android smartphone but I got a SIGSEV as soon as the app is starting.

I made many tests and I think that the error is coming from the `BindingContext`that i set here:

```
public partial class Login : ContentPage
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

Login is my main page.

Login.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ProjetX.Views.Login">
    <StackLayout Padding="10" Spacing="10">
        <Label Text="Login"></Label>
        <Entry Text="{Binding User.Login}"></Entry>

        <Label Text="Password"></Label>
        <Entry Text="{Binding User.Password}" IsPassword="True"></Entry>

        <Button Text="Connection" Command="{Binding ConnectClicked}"/>

        <Label Text="{Binding DisplayUserInfos}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Here is the code of my ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        ConnectClicked = new Command(loggIn);
        user = new User();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool LoggedIn { get; set; }

    public void onPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public User user;

    public User User
    {
        set
        {
            User = value;
        }
        get { return user; }
    }

    public string DisplayUserInfos()
    {
        return "User " + User.Login + " password " + User.Password + ((LoggedIn) ? " logged in " : "");
    }

    Command ConnectClicked { get; }

    void loggIn()
    {
        LoggedIn = true;
        DisplayUserInfos();
    }
}
```

When i remove the line `BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();` the error disapear and the app starts properly but I can't figure out where it's coming from exactly and how to solve it.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
 Stacktrace:
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228): 
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) <0x00047>
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (object,System.Reflection.BindingFlags,System.Reflection.Binder,object[],System.Globalization.CultureInfo) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (object,object[]) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/methodbase.cs:229
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (object,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,bool) [0x002d8] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:202
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (bool) [0x0003e] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:56
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.Binding.Apply (bool) [0x00020] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Binding.cs:114
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/BindablePropertyContext,object,bool,Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags,bool) [0x000e5] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:588
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,object,Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/SetValuePrivateFlags) [0x0015b] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:389
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.ApplyCore (object,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,bool) [0x001f9] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:174
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression.Apply (object,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty) [0x0006b] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindingExpression.cs:77
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.Binding.Apply (object,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty) [0x00042] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Binding.cs:126
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.ApplyBindings (bool) [0x0003b] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:420
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.ApplyBindings () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:125
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,object) [0x0005a] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:119
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element,object) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:493
04-23 17:22:09.376 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:341
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.View.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00042] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\View.cs:99
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,object) [0x00060] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:120
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.Element.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element,object) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:493
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedPage.SetChildInheritedBindingContext (Xamarin.Forms.Element,object) [0x00008] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\TemplatedPage.cs:35
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00021] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:341
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.Page.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Page.cs:206
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage.OnBindingContextChanged () [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ContentPage.cs:16
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.BindingContextPropertyChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject,object,object) [0x0000e] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:440
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/BindablePropertyContext,object,bool,Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags,bool) [0x00108] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:595
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,object,Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags,Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/SetValuePrivateFlags) [0x0015b] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:389
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,object,bool,bool) [0x0005f] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:542
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty,object) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:83
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.set_BindingContext (object) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:24
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at ProjetX.Views.Login..ctor () [0x0000f] in C:\Users\REMI\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ProjetX\ProjetX\ProjetX\Views\Login.xaml.cs:16
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at ProjetX.App..ctor () [0x0000f] in C:\Users\REMI\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ProjetX\ProjetX\ProjetX\App.xaml.cs:16
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at ProjetX.Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00027] in C:\Users\REMI\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\ProjetX\ProjetX\ProjetX.Android\MainActivity.cs:23
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentActivity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00013] in <425a51a3c9ba434799fb42d09e18fd4b>:0
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.397550ba-3fa4-4d79-af73-28d5114c0c2e (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00017] in <8c304e4006094a46a7950338a3b3cb5d>:0
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228):   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.397550ba-3fa4-4d79-af73-28d5114c0c2e (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00022] in <8c304e4006094a46a7950338a3b3cb5d>:0
04-23 17:22:09.377 E/mono-rt (31228): /proc/self/maps:
```

Comment: Could you share the Login page's XAML code? The stack trace is not helping to identify the issue

Comment: Just added it :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was infinite recursion in view model property. I was overloading == operator that was calling itself